# Migração de ambiente de desenvolvimento local de Windows para Mac

Tags: windows, osx, wamp

Gostaria de migrar para o Mac, porém tenho alguns receios em relação ao ambiente de desenvolvimento local.

A dúvida é em relação ao Apache, MySQL (e outras BD's), PHP e Node.js.

As questões são:

- Instalação e configuração: é desgastante, mais complexo e exige níveis de conhecimentos mais avançados de utilização do Mac?
- Compatibilidade: consigo utilizar todas as ferramentas/linguagens acima referidas na sua plenitude ou terei limitações? Por exemplo, algumas classes do PHP exigem DLL's.

A minha maior preocupação não é as ferramentas (adapto-me sem problemas) mas sim a limitação do sistema quando se trata de desenvolvimento localhost, se vou conseguir testar todas as funcionalidades de um site sem ter problemas de compatibilidade.

Comment: Não fica mais difício. porque o OS X é baseado em BSD. Você pode usar ele pelo terminal de controle,"igual um linux". Único problema são programas pagos, caso você já tenha no windows.

Comment: eu acho que pode ter uma resposta objetiva sim para sua pergunta, eu inclusive gostaria muito de ver a resposta, eu torci para aparecer uma resposta antes que ela fosse fechada inclusive, pois dependendo da resposta muitas vezes acabam percebendo que a pergunta pode sim fazer parte do escopo do site, mas infelizmente ela foi fechada sumariamente, gostaria pelo menos que tivesse demorado um pouco mais para fechar, mas enfim.. sugiro você se acalmar e criar uma pergunta no meta, ou editar sua pergunta para torná-la mais objetiva, se é que isso é possível

Comment: @Math esse é o problema da comunidade, pessoas podem tomar decisões sem saber o que estão de fato a fazer. É óbvio que a pergunta tem sim a ver com programação, indirectamente, mas tem sim. Queria saber as dificuldades encontradas na programação para quem migrou para o MAC, mas penso que nem se esforçaram para entender o escopo da pergunta. Onde vou encontrar programadores que migraram para MAC, se não podemos fazer essa pergunta aqui, sinceramente, não sei onde. De qualquer modo votei para reabrir a pergunta, ainda faltam votos.

Comment: A pergunta, além de ser ampla demais, tem uma parte para qual qualquer resposta é pura opinião (no tocante a migração ser desgastante e exigir conhecimentos avançados). Você também pede recomendações de ferramentas no terceiro item, o que é [um tópico um tanto sensível aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/devemos-aceitar-questoes-de-recomendacao).

Comment: @Renan não vejo outra forma de perguntar sobre uma migração, é impossível fazer uma pergunta mais directa. Listei quais os programas/linguagens que me preocupam e limitei a instalação/configuração e compatibilidade. Isso é ser amplo demais? Tem alguma sugestão melhor, penso que tens pontuação para sugerir algo melhor.

Comment: **Pontuação não tem nada a ver com isso.** Ademais, eu adoraria fazer algumas perguntas do tipo "como montar um ambiente de desenvolvimento para Android" ou "Melhores práticas para montar uma base de dados de preços de produtos", mas acredito que são tópicos amplos demais e localizados demais. E a pergunta envolve programação apenas tangencialmente - nenhum conceito de programação foi discutido diretamente. Substitua suas ferramentas citadas pelo Office, por exemplo, e a pergunta não muda quase nada.

Comment: @Renan a pontuação sim, acima dos 1000 pontos podes editar sem necessidade de uma aprovação. Em relação a pergunta, você está considerando 20% da questão e ignorando os 80%. Concordo com o que você disse em relação as ferramentas adequadas, por isso removi esse tópico da questão.

Comment: Eu diria 50% agora. A parte sobre desgaste ainda é questão de opinião, porém a parte sobre compatibilidade de bibliotecas é objetiva. De qualquer forma, retiro meu voto negativo e voto por fechamento.

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo discutida em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1234/pergunta-descontextualizada-se-o-conteudo-for-indirectamente-sobre-programacao

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Instalação e configuração: é desgastante, mais complexo e exige níveis de conhecimentos mais avançados de utilização do Mac?

Apache e PHP já vêm instalados no Mac por padrão. Se quiser é possível substituí-los por outras versões. No caso dessas ferramentas, e de outras como o MySQL, você tem duas opções de instalação.

- Compilar e instalar via linha de comando.
- Instalar por meio de um gerenciador de pacotes como o [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), também via linha de comando. É bem simples, basta um comando.

Ambas as opções requerem a instalação das ferramentas de desenvolvedor do Mac – que incluem compilador C, entre outras funções. Instale essas ferramentas, você vai precisar delas.

Outras ferramentas, como o Node, possuem instaladores para Mac, e nesse caso a instalação é bem simples.

> Compatibilidade: consigo utilizar todas as ferramentas/linguagens acima referidas na sua plenitude ou terei limitações? Por exemplo, algumas classes do php exigem DLL's.

O Mac não usa DLLs, e sim extensões compiladas num outro formato, como no Linux. Não sei quais extensões você usa, mas as principais estão sim disponíveis para Mac. No entanto, a instalação de algumas delas é mais complicada que no Windows, pode ser necessário compilá-las manualmente. Para o feijão com arroz, uma instalação comum do PHP (como a que vem com o XAMPP, por exemplo) é suficiente.

> Ferramentas: as mesmas ferramentas, como por exemplo, MySQl Workbench, possuem as mesmas funcionalidades? Existem ferramentas mais apropriadas para Mac na manipulação de base de dados e para programação?

Isso não tem resposta precisa, mas várias ferramentas disponíveis para Windows também existem para Mac – incluindo o Workbench e o SublimeText. Você vai precisar experimentar para ver quais ferramentas prefere.

#### Minha experiência pessoal

A migração para Mac é muito agradável para quem tem familiaridade com o Linux e gosta de usar o Terminal. Com certeza há diferenças e coisas que acabam levando um tempo para se acostumar, mas para mim valeu a pena, e dificilmente volto para o Windows. Quando preciso usar Windows (por exemplo, para testar algo no Internet Explorer), recorro a máquinas virtuais.

No entanto, só você poderá avaliar se vai achar vantajoso ou não, e só vai saber isso na prática. Pegue um Mac emprestado por um tempo, ou compre um considerando que pode vendê-lo se não se adaptar.

Comment: Sim, as ferramentas é uma pergunta ampla demais, por isso disse que não me preocupava. Eu já trabalhei com o MAC aqui na empresa, foi um dia só, não deu para testar compatibilidades, etc... mas sem receios posso dizer que o conjunto hardware/software (OSX) é muito superior ao que encontramos no mercado e quando se trata de fluidez é unânime.

Comment: A sua resposta responde as minhas dúvidas. Ninguém melhor para responder do que um utilizador do MAC. Estou mais confiante/decidido a apostar na migração.

Comment: Mas não precisa aceitar minha resposta tão rápido! Isso pode desencorajar outras pessoas de responderem também,  @Filipe.

Comment: OK, tens toda razão, queria aceitar antes que fechem novamente a questão, já votaram a favor do fechamento do tópico.

Comment: Testa primeiro em uma VirtualBox ou em outro computador. para depois migrar e ter mais intimidade. Fiz assim quando migrei para ARCH.